# primefaces disable commandButton

Tags: primefaces, commandbutton, disabled-control

I have below code for primefaces `p:commandButton`. I have set update and `oncomplete` attributes to disable `commandButton` in `p:panelGrid` of `"panelGrid1s4a3b1"` and show messages on `p:message` of `"customMessage1s4"`. But does not know why these two not working. Anyone can help me to make them work?

```
<p:commandButton id="cmdVerify1s4a2" widgetVar="cmdVerify1s4a2" 
value="Verify" action="approveProfileQualifications" 
update="@([id$=panelGrid1s4a3b1]), @([id$=customMessage1s4])" 
oncomplete="PF(cmdVerify1s4a2).disable(); PF('cmdReject1s4a2').disable();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating is right. Change your `p:commandButton` little

```
update="panelGrid1s4a3b1 customMessage1s4"
```

while I believe your `p:messages` like

```
<p:messages id="customMessage1s4" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
```

**MORE**

You can also use keywords to update:

> ```
> Keywords are the easier way to reference components, they resolve to ids so that if an id changes,
> the reference does not need to change. Core JSF provides a couple of keywords and PrimeFaces
> provides more along with composite expression support.
> ```

Following are the keywords.

> @this Standard Current component. @all Standard Whole view. @form
>   Standard Closest ancestor form of current component. @none Standard No
>   component. @namingcontainer PrimeFaces Closest ancestor naming
>   container of current component. @parent PrimeFaces Parent of the
>   current component. @composite PrimeFaces Closest composite component
>   ancestor. @child(n) PrimeFaces nth child. @row(n) PrimeFaces nth row.
>   @previous PrimeFaces Previous sibling. @next PrimeFaces Next sibling.
>   @widgetVar(name) PrimeFaces Component with given widgetVar.